# openai_ros + noetic + turtlebot2 :: start_training.launch gives "No suscribers to cmd_vel_pub" error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDITED**

I followed the tutorial "[OpenAI_ROS with Turtlebot2 Step by Step #Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwGj1rjVtw4&ab_channel=TheConstruct)" from The Construct, but in my local pc. I have everything running but start_training.launch is giving an error

```
No suscribers to cmd_vel_pub yet so we wait and try again
```

I`m not realizing what is missing. More detail bellow,

First I ran

```
roslaunch gym_construct main.launch gui:=true
```

which looks good, Gazebo maze environment was started, with output:

```
roslaunch gym_construct main.launch gui:=true
... logging to /home/fede/.ros/log/f5a5f724-020c-11ed-a6dc-4396d1fd14f6/roslaunch-slam-80673.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://slam:33643/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /home/fede/aslam_...
 * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [80721]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to f5a5f724-020c-11ed-a6dc-4396d1fd14f6
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [80750]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [80757]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [80762]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-4]: started with pid [80767]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5]: started with pid [80768]
process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [80769]
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [80770]
process[robot_state_publisher-8]: started with pid [80771]
[ INFO] [1657649021.496438617]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1657649021.497066737]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1657649021.576661728]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1657649021.577317914]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1657649022.289070697]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1657649022.301902848, 0.013000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[ INFO] [1657649023.247775734, 0.374000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1657649023.249326603, 0.374000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1657649023.401860442, 0.374000000]: Starting plugin Kobuki(ns = //)
[ WARN] [1657649023.401895021, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): missing <rosDebugLevel> default is na
[ INFO] [1657649023.402490716, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): <tf_prefix> = 
[ WARN] [1657649023.402784182, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): missing <update_rate> default is 0
[ INFO] [1657649023.402896134, 0.374000000]: Will publish tf. [mobile_base]
[ INFO] [1657649023.404077961, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise joint_states[joint_states]!
[ INFO] [1657649023.404425272, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise Odometry[odom]!
[ INFO] [1657649023.405927719, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Try to subscribe to mobile_base/commands/motor_power!
[ INFO] [1657649023.407269293, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Try to subscribe to mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry!
[ INFO] [1657649023.408995416, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Try to subscribe to mobile_base/commands/velocity!
[ INFO] [1657649023.409464566, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise Cliff[mobile_base/events/cliff]!
[ INFO] [1657649023.409769126, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise Bumper[mobile_base/events/bumper]!
[ INFO] [1657649023.410057637, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise IMU[mobile_base/sensors/imu_data]!
[ INFO] [1657649023.410357902, 0.374000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise Core[mobile_base/sensors/core]!
[ INFO] [1657649023.410372466, 0.374000000]: GazeboRosKobuki plugin ready to go! [mobile_base]
[spawn_turtlebot_model-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/fede/.ros/log/f5a5f724-020c-11ed-a6dc-4396d1fd14f6/spaw
```

Then, I ran

```
roslaunch turtle2_openai_ros_example start_training_maze.launch
```

with output:

```
... logging to /home/fede/.ros/log/f5a5f724-020c-11ed-a6dc-4396d1fd14f6/roslaunch-slam-101541.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://slam:36025/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.14
 * /turtlebot2/alpha: 1.0
 * /turtlebot2/angular_speed: 0.3
 * /turtlebot2/danger_laser_value: 2
 * /turtlebot2/end_episode_points: 200
 * /turtlebot2/epsilon: 0.9
 * /turtlebot2/epsilon_discount: 0.999
 * /turtlebot2/forwards_reward: 5
 * /turtlebot2/gamma: 0.7
 * /turtlebot2/init_linear_forward_speed: 0.0
 * /turtlebot2/init_linear_turn_speed: 0.0
 * /turtlebot2/linear_forward_speed: 0.5
 * /turtlebot2/linear_turn_speed: 0.1
 * /turtlebot2/max_laser_value: 6
 * /turtlebot2/middle_laser_value: 1
 * /turtlebot2/middle_range: 1.0
 * /turtlebot2/min_laser_value: 0
 * /turtlebot2/min_range: 0.5
 * /turtlebot2/n_actions: 3
 * /turtlebot2/n_observations: 6
 * /turtlebot2/nepisodes: 500
 * /turtlebot2/new_ranges: 5
 * /turtlebot2/nsteps: 500
 * /turtlebot2/number_of_sectors: 3
 * /turtlebot2/number_splits: 10
 * /turtlebot2/pos_step: 0.016
 * /turtlebot2/running_step: 0.06
 * /turtlebot2/safe_laser_value: 0
 * /turtlebot2/speed_step: 1.0
 * /turtlebot2/turn_reward: 1
 * /turtlebot2/wait_time: 0.1

NODES
  /
    example_turtlebot2_maze_qlearn (turtle2_openai_ros_example/my_start_qlearning_maze.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[example_turtlebot2_maze_qlearn-1]: started with pid [101574]
/home/fede/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/spaces/box.py:84: UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  logger.warn(f"Box bound precision lowered by casting to {self.dtype}")
[ERROR] [1657657392.794681, 8365.484000]: NOT Initialising Simulation Physics Parameters
[WARN] [1657657392.797549, 8365.487000]: Start Init ControllersConnection
[WARN] [1657657392.798301, 8365.487000]: END Init ControllersConnection
[DEBUG][1657751975.677842, 115.074000][/turtlebot2_maze/TurtleBot2MazeEnv._check_publishers_connection:200]: No susbribers to _cmd_vel_pub yet so we wait and try again
[DEBUG][1657751975.809566, 115.174000][/turtlebot2_maze/TurtleBot2MazeEnv._check_publishers_connection:200]: No susbribers to _cmd_vel_pub yet so we wait and try again
[DEBUG][1657751975.954183, 115.274000][/turtlebot2_maze/TurtleBot2MazeEnv._check_publishers_connection:200]: No susbribers to _cmd_vel_pub yet so we wait and try again
[DEBUG][1657751976.115260, 115.375000][/turtlebot2_maze/TurtleBot2MazeEnv._check_publishers_connection:200]: No susbribers to _cmd_vel_pub yet so we wait and try again
```

And keeps giving this error about no suscribers, but I don`t know what is the problem.

Please Help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403707/openai_ros-+-noetic-+-turtlebot2-::-start_training.launch-gives-%22no-suscribers-to-cmd_vel_pub%22-error/) by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2022-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) on 2022-07-14**:
(Self-reflection). I presume that `example_turtlebot2_maze_qlearn` node is waiting for Turtlebot to be suscribed to `cmd_vel` topic. But it is not. However, if I launch `roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch` I am able to control Turtlebot in Gazebo. Then, I think Turtlebot is suscribed to one of the `cmd_vel_mux` members, but no to the specific `cmd_vel` topic the problematic node is waiting to.
I can not figure out how to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED!

Finally I found in line 77 of `turtlebot2_env.py` file a publisher initialization @ topic `/cmd_vel` (which is has not suscriptors). So I changed for `/cmd_vel_mux/iniput/teleop` and seems to be working.

---

Originally posted by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) with karma: 81 on 2022-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jandisoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/121744/jandisoon/) on 2022-11-09**:
can you please help me to install openai in ros noetic i have a lot of problems

**Comment by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) on 2022-11-09**:
Hi jandisoon. I dont know if this the right place, maybe start a new question, and I will help you to do it. Let me know which part of the process I giving problems to you.
I have installed openai from The Construct, and It was not so easy. But I think If you install from Stable Baseline 3, I would be easier.

**Comment by [jandisoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/121744/jandisoon/) on 2022-11-10**:
i trying to find some solution the the problems but now i get this problem `[ERROR] [1668082595.325205]: Current /scan not ready yet, retrying for getting laser_scan` when i run this launch file `roslaunch my_turtlebot3_openai_example start_training.launch`

**Comment by [jandisoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/121744/jandisoon/) on 2022-11-10**:
this is my question here [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/409225/turtlebot3-openai-example-doesnt-work/)